# selected multiple from from the multi select column in the view file after calling the function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

How to pass the value from multiselect column  from view into controller Get Method. I am trying to pass the value from dropdownDepot  into the controller 
argument List Department. Please help

```html
public class ReportViewModel
    {
         
        public int DepotNo { get; set; }
        public List<int> Department { get; set; }
        
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
public IActionResult EmployeeView(ReportViewModel report, List<int> Department,int DepotNo = 0)
{
     List<EmployeeWorkTimeSettingsModel> log = new List<EmployeeWorkTimeSettingsModel>();
     log = ReportService.GetDepotEmployeeWorkHrsReport(connectionSettings, (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID") ?? 0).ToString(),
     String.Join(",", report.DepotNo), String.Join(",", report.Department));
     ViewBag.EmpviewReport = log;
}

<div class="controls col-sm-9">

       <select asp-for="DepotNo" class="form-control" id="dropdownDepot" asp-items="@ViewBag.UserDepots" onchange="FillEmployee()"    data-role="select"></select>
       <span asp-validation-for="DepotNo" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="controls col-sm-9">
            <select id="dropdownDepartment" class="form-control" asp-for="Department" asp-items="@ViewBag.UserDepartments"  onchange="FillEmployee()" 
            data-role="select"></select>
                                
</div>

 $('#dropdownDepartment').multiselect({
        columns: 1,
        placeholder: 'Select Department',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        maxHeight: 300
    });

function FillEmployee() {
        var href = '/Report/EmployeeView?depot=' + $("#dropdownDepot option:selected").val() + '&department=' +  Get the Value from multiselect departments;
        $("#lnkFilter").attr('href', href);
        $("#lnkFilter").click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ajax to pass all your data to controller when you select

```
function FillEmployee() {
   $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/Report/EmployeeView?DepotNo=' + $('#dropdownDepot').val() + '&department=' + $('#dropdownDepartment').val().join('&department='),

         success: function (result) {
                        console.log('Data received: ');
                        console.log(result);
                    }
      });
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
 public IActionResult EmployeeView([FromQuery]List<int> Department, [FromQuery]int DepotNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `val()` directly on the select element, without having to filter by the selected options first. When you do so on a select multiple, you get back an array of selected values:

```
$('#dropdownDepot').val() // single selected value
```

And

```
$('dropdownDepartment').val() // array of selected values
```

In order for the array to bind properly, you'll need to actually repeat the `department` param for each selected value:

```
&department=value1&department=value2&department=value3
```

Something like the following should work for that:

```
'&department=' + $('#dropdownDepartment').val().join('&department=')
```

Comment: Another problem  I am facing , after each selection the prior selected value will disappear from  the multiselect after passing  into the function. When I comment the function FillEmployee(),  the value of selected department will stay otherwise note. How can I resolve this problem. The reason  for  the  deselecting the selected department is the code $("#lnkFilter").click();  How can I pass the argument  without calling $("#lnkFilter").click();  Please can you help ?